# programmatically insert mail mergefield into hyperlink in a word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically insert mail mergefield into hyperlink in a word document.

In ms word application this is easily accomplished with the following code when in code-view(ALT+F9):
`{HYPERLINK "http://example.com?id={MERGEFILED ID}"}`

I consulted stackoverflow and google but came up empty-handed.
How could I accomplish something like above snippet via C# word interoperability library?

Right now this is what I have:

```
using mso = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
public class Test
{
    public void GenerateDynamicHyperlinkWithMergeField()
    {
        mso.Application app = new mso.Application();
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        mso.Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        mso.Range range = app.Selection.Range;

        // this is hyperlinked correctly
        mso.Hyperlink hl = document.Hyperlinks.Add(range, "http://example.com?id=", ref missing, ref missing, "textToDisplay", ref missing);   

        // this mergfield is outside of hyperlink
        mso.MailMerge merge = app.ActiveDocument.MailMerge;
        mso.MailMergeField mf = merge.Fields.Add(range, "id");

        // inserts mergefield code into hyperlink, but not as recognizable code by word application
        mso.Hyperlink hl2 = document.Hyperlinks.Add(range, "http://example.com?id=" + mf.Code.Text, ref missing, ref missing, "textToDisplay", ref missing);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
To clarify what result is expected in word document;
I want this: `{HYPERLINK "http://example.com?id={MERGEFILED ID}"}`
But I get this with the above function: `{HYPERLINK "http://example.com?id="}{MERGEFILED ID}`

Comment: what is the error your getting?

Comment: no error, all is fine code-wise. Only the result is not what I want.
I want this: `{HYPERLINK "http://example.com?id={MERGEFILED ID}"}`
But I get this: `{HYPERLINK "http://example.com?id="}{MERGEFILED ID}`

Comment: Did you already try the concatenation before inserting it?

Comment: There's some generic code in one of the references here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774411/creating-a-nested-field-with-word-interop/18290056#18290056
You may find my comments on that question useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string myLink = "http://example.com?id=" + mf.Code.Text; 
mso.Hyperlink hl2 = document.Hyperlinks.Add(range, myString, ref missing, ref missing, "textToDisplay", ref missing);
```

Comment: I tried concatenation before inserting hyperlink to no avail

Answer (score 0):

This might be a red herring, but have you noticed it says `MERGEFILED` and not `MERGEFIELD`?
I only bring it up because it's in all instances you mention it.